# Overhead in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, h2

I have a Restful microservice that uses Spring-Boot and Spring-Batch. When I run it locally it uses H2 database. Sending requests to microservice, I see the Spring Batch serializes the context of Job. Using a tool for profiling I see the microservice stays too much on this serialization. 
Table used: BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT.

Call graph:
[image]

Do you have any idea how the serialization of context can be disabled?

Thank you

Comment: You can't disable it although you can change how the serialization is done.  That being said, what is in the context that is causing that deep of a stack?

Comment: The problem was the results were saved to Job Context. It exceeded the limit 2500 chars and this causes the overhead. Somehow I should change the logic. Thanks,